# How can I write to a specific line range with sed or awk?

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I simply want to write a command's output to a file's particular line range.

For instance first command should be written into range 0-1000 then second command into 1001-2000 etc.

I've successfully managed to write to a single line with `sed -i` command which doesn't help me at all.

What I lastly tried in a **for loop** is;

```
    for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do
        awk "NR >=$counter && NR <=$((counter + 1002)) {print $(eval $cmd)}" file > $logfile
        counter=$((counter + 1003))
    done
```

which throws **argument is too long** error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I can't imagine what you're trying to do. Please [edit] your question to include an example with concise, testable sample input and expected output using blocks of, say, 4 lines instead of 1000. You could use `seq`, for example, in place of `$cmd` if you need a tool that produces some number of lines of output to use in the example.

Comment: Is the output of $(eval $cmd) expected to always be exactly 1000 lines?

Comment: In fact the question is pretty clear, I want to write a bunch of lines which could be counted between 0-1000, into a file to a specific range. And for same file I want to write something else to the next range like 1001-2000

Answer (score 0):

Instead of evaluating the same command and incrementing `counter` on thousands of `awk` iterations - use the following `sed` optimized approach:

```
cnt=1
for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do
    cmd_out="$(eval $cmd)"
    sed -n "$cnt,$((cnt + 1002)) s/.*/$cmd_out/p" 10lines.txt >> $logfile
    cnt=$((cnt + 1003))
done
```

But if don't actually use the contents of the processed file - you can just iterate through inner ranges and print/append the same command output to a destination file.

Comment: I didn't get this part: `s/.*/$cmd_out/p"` actually

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? The `awk` script either truncates or pads to 1000 lines.

```
$ cat foo.sh
for cmd in 'seq 5' 'seq 3000'; do
        $cmd | awk 'NR > 1000 { exit } END { while (NR++ < 1000) print ""} 1'
done >foo.txt
$ bash foo.sh
$ wc -l foo.txt
2000 foo.txt
$ head foo.txt
1
2
3
4
5





$ tail foo.txt
991
992
993
994
995
996
997
998
999
1000
```

Comment: I really don't want to use anything other than bash

Comment: @SercanOzdemir try this version which just uses `awk`.